# Cannot get Babel to recognize "import" keyword on module import

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to create a "template" gulpfile from an npm install. In the `gulpfile.babel.js` for a project.

In my project, my .babelrc is defined as follows:

```
 {
      "ignore": false,
      "presets": [ "es2015" ]
 }
```

I reference the gulpfile in another project. For the sake of the question, let us call the required project "test". This is in my gulpfile, referencing an export I make from the npm installed "test" package.

```
import tasks from 'test/gulpfile.babel'
```

This throws the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { argv }
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Is there a reason I cannot babel load something from another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, at least for the time being, is that this is not a possibility. It seems as though there is an issue with Babel whereby `node_modules` are always ignored via the `.babelrc` file, but work as expected with the CLI.

See: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726

Answer (score 0):

make sure there's a 'use strict' at the top of the file. If not, I'm out of answers.

Comment: at this point I'm willing to try anything, will let you know if that works

Comment: damn. sorry mate. If it's any help - I get this kind of error only when I try to do a vanilla `node file.js` instead of `babel file.js`.

Comment: Thanks for your help all the same!